# How do i keep a Turtle in the foreground while 'spawning' other turtles?

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Im creating a small retro space invaders type game and wanted to hide the turtles being spawned in the background of the program while having a "loading" screen in front. is their any way to do this? (This is the first question i've asked on here so i'm not sure what code i need to include)

Comment: Today I learned about Turtles and I love the kind of questions and answers it can generate. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule, turtles can never appear behind anything drawn by turtles.  I recommend you put up your "loading" screen message, and create your turtles invisibly:

```
turtle_4 = Turtle(visible=False)
```

Then, when you're ready, take down your loading screen message and use `showturtle()` to make your fully configured and positioned turtles visible.